# How to reduce the label font in bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap to design the form, however I have an issue with the label font (big and bold)
How I can reduce the font and remove the bold? see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mhussein/20psbpdj/12/)

```
    <form class="form-horizontal">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="sel" class="col-md-2 control-label">Selecte:</label>
    <div class="col-md-10"> 
        <select id="sel" class="form-control input-sm"></select>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code (create a CSS for this):

```
@media (max-width: @screen-xs) {
    .form-group label{font-size: 10px;}
}

@media (max-width: @screen-sm) {
    .form-group label{font-size: 14px;}
}

.form-group label{
    font-size: 1.4em;
}
```

Specify the font size that you need. This would alter the font size with window resize. There is no bootstrap class to accomplish this yet to my knowledge.

Comment: the problem with this solution is: I have an option to the users to maximize and minimize the page fonts (A+ & A-) it will not work if I use the customize CSS. Any idea if I can use bootstrap class for that?

Answer (score 9):

I could do it with "small", example :

```
<label class="control-label col-sm-3 small">Email:</label>
```

Comment: Awesome. Simple is always sweet..!!